# Выборка повторяющегося id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

уже который день ломаю голову , все никак не могу решить проблему. По клику на кнопку добавляю товар в корзину, он туда приходит  по id товара ,записывая этот id в сессию. Допустим я несколько раз добавил один и тот же товар , то есть id будет одинаковый и прийти может несколько раз, но товар с этим id выводится только 1 раз .В силу неопытности не знаю как сделать правильную выборку, прошу вашей помощи!

сама кнопка

```
<a class="mt-3 btn btn-info cart" href='../controllers/cart.php.?prodId=<?=$id;?>'> Добавить в корзину </a>
```

обработчик

```
session_start();
require_once '../DB.php';

    if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
        $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
    }
    $prodId = isset($_GET['prodId']) ? $_GET['prodId'] : null;
    if(!empty($prodId)) {
        $_SESSION['cart'][] = $prodId;
    }

    $cartId = $_SESSION['cart'];

    if (isset($cartId)){

        $matches = implode(',', $cartId);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE id IN ($matches)";
```

так же пробовал что-то подобное,но не уверен что верная запись

```
$sql = "SELECT * , COUNT(*) FROM `post` WHERE id IN ($matches) GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*)>=1 ";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не надо хранить товары из корзины в сессии! о_0

А если клиент выйдет из аккаунта? Он же потеряет все свои товары.

Для правильной реализации вашей задумки вам необходимо:

1. Сделать таблицу в БД. Например, `basket` с полями `id`, `clientId`, `productId`.
2. Вместо вашего обработчика написать:

2.1) Проверку на возможность пользователю добавлять товары в корзину(хотя бы авторизован ли пользователь или нет)

2.2) Проверку товара на существование

2.3) Делать запись в таблицу, если 2.1 и 2.2 успешны

2.4) Выводить все товары из корзины, доступные пользователю

3. Также не понятно зачем добавлять 2 одинаковых товара в корзину. Если это так необходимо, то вы можете также добавить поле дата добавления (`added`) в таблицу в БД, чтобы чуть проще их различать было, помимо получения его по `id`.

И код ваш будет следующим:

Обработчик, в который пользователь попадёт после перехода по ссылке:

```
session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['clientId']) && !empty($_GET['prodId']))
{
    $clientId = $_SESSION['clientId'];
    $prodId = $_GET['prodId'];
    // Также Вы не указали как называется таблица с товарами, пусть будет products
    $availableProducts = "SELECT id FROM products";
    // Вы не показали как делаете выборку из БД поэтому тут будет выполнение данного запроса
    if(in_array($prodId, $availableProducts))
    {
        // И поле added, если надо
        $query = "INSERT INTO basket (clientId, productId) value ($clientId, $prodId)";
        // Ваш код для вызова запроса на вставку в БД.
        // После успешной вставки переходим на страницу корзины
        // Либо возвращаемся на туже страницу с товарами
        header('Location: some/link/basket.php');
    }
}
```

Страница вывода товаров из корзины:

```
session_start();
$clientId = $_SESSION['clientId'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM products
INNER JOIN basket on products.id = basket.productId
WHERE basket.clientId = $clientId";
// Ваш код для вызова запроса на получение данных из БД.
// Вывод данных
```